# Mysql Spring Data JPA boolean

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with boolean type in my Action class.

My table in mysql have column 'removed' which is BIT(1) type with default value 0.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Actions")
     public class Action {
      //other fields

      @Column(name = "removed")
      private boolean removed;

      //setters and getters
      }
```

When I tried to compile my Spring Boot App I saw errors like:

```
          Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property by found for type boolean! Traversed path: Action.removed.
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:339) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:363) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
            ... 44 common frames omitted
```

I tried other anotations to my Action removed field like:

```
@Column(name = "removed",columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)
@Column(name = "removed",columnDefinition = "TINYINT", length = 1)
```

or

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
```

but no does not work...

My ActionDao interface:

```
 public interface ActionDao extends CrudRepository<Action, Integer>{
public Action findByActionname(String actionname);
public List<Action> findAllByRemovedByOrderByActionnameAsc(boolean removed);}
```

my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
```

and application.properties

```
        spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/System?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=test
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
    spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 5.5.52-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: What happens when you try to use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`?

Comment: If you're using 5.5 then the mapping should work.  Try Serge's suggestion and use `Boolean`.

Comment: The same problem... It isn`t working...

Comment: When I try 
`@Column(name = "removed",columnDefinition = "TINYINT", length = 1)
private Boolean removed;`
i have error : 
`Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [removed] in table [Actions]; found [bit (Types#BIT)], but expecting [tinyint (Types#BOOLEAN)]`

Comment: Look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html), `BIT(1)` should map to `java.lang.Boolean`.

Comment: Now, i use BIT(1) with default value '0' in my database and everywhere use Boolean class.
The classfield `removed` have annotation `@Column(name = "removed",columnDefinition = "BIT", length = 1)`
The same error:
`Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property by found for type Boolean! Traversed path: Action.removed.`

Comment: I think your query is not correct. 
findAllByRemovedByOrderByActionnameAsc the 2nd By is wrong in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your searching the problem at the wrong location. Not the removed is the issue, it is your query method.

```
public List<Action> findAllByRemovedByOrderByActionnameAsc(boolean removed);
```

It should be:

```
public List<Action> findAllByRemovedOrderByActionnameAsc(boolean removed);
```

If we take a look back to your error message

'No property **by** found for type boolean! Traversed path: Action.removed.'

After by follows usually the name of the property.